# How to unpack a tuple when it's length is 1 generated from `itertools.product` using only 1 set as input argument?

Tags: python, dictionary, tuples, python-itertools

I'm trying to set default values of multiple dictionaries by iterating over multiple sets using `itertools.product`. This works well when a dictionary's keys are tuples. So each `value` from `itertools.product` which is a tuple and that can be used as `dict_x.setfault(value,[])`. The problem arises when a dictionary's key is a single value.

```
# example of problem 
set_a = {1,2,3,4}

dict_y = {1:'blah',2:'blahblah'}

for key in itertools.product(set_a):
 dict_y.setdefault(key,'hi')

print(dict_y)

# output: {1:'blah',2:'blahblah',(1,):'hi', (2,):'hi', (3,):'hi', (4,):'hi'}
```

So the keys {1,2} should not have been used to set to default in dict_y. Preferred output is `{1:'blah',2:'blahblah',3:'hi', 4:'hi'}`

I'm using loops, lookups, list comprehensions to iterate over all dictionaries and the sets that are needed to set defaults. I don't have `set_a` or `dict_y` explictly. Hence it would be difficult to treat cases with single value keys separately (like avoiding use of itertools). It would be helpful to get desired `key` in `setdefault for loop`  if:

1. There's a way to unpack tuples of length 1 only or
2. Unpack and pack tuples since `dict_y[1] == dict_y[(1)] != dict_y[(1,)]`
3. Prevent getting a tuple when `itertools.product` has only 1 set as input argument

Comment: How about a conditional: `if len(set_a) == 1: try: key = key[0], except TypeError: pass ...`?

Comment: Yes, that would work. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There might be some ambiguity in your data representation. The first paragraph
seems to suggest that the preferred approach is to have a dictionary with keys
based on tuples.

If that's the case, how about the following code:

```
import itertools

set_a = {1,2,3,4}
dict_y = {(1,): 'blah', (2,): 'blahblah'}
for key in itertools.product(set_a):
   dict_y.setdefault(key,'hi')
print(dict_y)
# {(1,): 'blah', (2,): 'blahblah', (3,): 'hi', (4,): 'hi'}
```

Your example seems to based on scalar keys. This code would work in such
a case, not needing `itertools.product` at all:

```
set_a = {1,2,3,4}
dict_y = {1: 'blah', 2: 'blahblah'}
for key in set_a:
   dict_y.setdefault(key, 'hi')
print(dict_y)
# {1: 'blah', 2: 'blahblah', 3: 'hi', 4: 'hi'}
```

Comment: Thanks @VirtualScooter for attempting an answer. To clarify: I'm iterating through multiple dictionaries with different types of keys (scalars and tuples). Since I'm using `itertools` to get all possible keys for setting default, the case when the keys are supposed to scalars are also converted to tuple even when I'd like them to be scalars. That's when @pylang's comment was helpful. If the keys are to be scalar (by checking it's length), unpack the tuple using an `if` condition. So the question is resolved with @pylang's comment.